# How to make this simple function generic in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, generic-programming

**Aim to Achieve :**

I want the Function to accept List(Of String), Array & String and similarly return List(Of String), Array & String respectively. The Function simply adds a string (month) to the input collection. I just want to use it for string, array and list with needing to think of conversions.

I have a simple function :

```
Private Function addMonth(ByVal stringList As List(Of String), ByVal month As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim names As New List(Of String)
    For Each name In stringList
        names.Add(name + " (" + month + ")")
    Next name
    Return names
End Function
```

How can I use generic type 'T' to achieve my aim ?

It would really save me a lot of tension.. !

I am new to VB.Net.. and don't know much about generic functions !

Comment: Risking down votes again by answering your question :) Older version of VB used to have datatype of Variant in .net it is replace with Object

Comment: Its not like that.. sir.. you can answer.. I won't vote down.. may be some coincident..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need to write a new function for this.  Just use `.Select()`:

```
myStringList.Select(Function(s) s & " (" & month & ")")
```

But since you also want to accept a string input, you can overload the function like this:

```
Private Function AddMonth(ByVal list As IEnumerable(Of String), ByVal month As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    return list.Select(Function(s) s & " (" & month & ")")
End Function

Private Function AddMonth(ByVal list As String, ByVal month As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
   Return New String() {list & " (" & month & ")"}
End Function
```

Note that all of these return `IEnumerable(Of String)`, and this is just as it should be.  It's easy to convert this to a string array or string list later, but most of the time you don't want to. It's much better for performance to keep treating an object as an IEnumerable for as long as possible.

Comment: Can we merge these 2 functions into 1 somehow ?
By using generics.. like T ?

This will work great.. but if these could be merged somehow, then that would be great !

Comment: Well.. that was great.. but it would be awesome if you can merge the 2 functions into 1 and maintain the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: If what you want is a function that can take *either* a `String` *or* a `String()` array, you can accomplish that with the `ParamArray` keyword. But it needs to be the *last* argument passed to the function; so you'd just need to reverse the order of the arguments:

```
Private Function AddMonth(ByVal month As String, ByVal ParamArray list() As String) As List(Of String)
    ' Same code as below
End Function
```

This would allow you to call it like this:

```
Dim withMonths = AddMonth("March", "Report")
```

And also like this:

```
Dim withMonths = AddMonth("March", "Report", "Memo")
```

And also like this:

```
Dim list = New String() { "Report", "Memo" }
Dim withMonths = AddMonth("March", list)
```

Note that while this appears to achieve what you're after, it's actually a bit *less* flexible as it requires you to pass in parameters either in the form above (each individually) or as an actual `String()` array, rather than just any `IEnumerable(Of String)` such as `List(Of String)`.

---

**Original answer**:

```
Private Function AddMonth(Of T)(ByVal list As IEnumerable(Of T), ByVal month As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim names As New List(Of String)
    For Each name In list
        ' Using String.Concat avoids the possibility
        ' of a NullReferenceException
        names.Add(String.Concat(name) + " (" + month + ")")
    Next name
    Return names
End Function
```

Comment: Let me try and I will let you know !

Comment: How can I manage String as input for list in this ?

str.ToArray makes it a character array.. 
How should I convert str to array of String in the best possible way ?

Comment: @Yugal: How do you want to convert a string to an array of strings? Give an example input/output.

Comment: Well.. it will be like addMonth("Report".ToArray,"March") !!

And.. "Report".ToArray makes it a character array instead of String array. I don't want to make it look dirty, so what would you suggest ?

Comment: @Yugal Jindle: addMonth({"Report"},"March")